# Acceder a tabla con Django

Tags: base-de-datos, django, django-models

Bueno yo cree dos modelos de tabla que pongo a continuacion:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    opciones = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)    
    votos = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    class Meta:
            verbose_name= "Opción" 
            verbose_name_plural= "Opciones"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.opciones

class Encuesta(models.Model):
    pregunta = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    opciones = models.ManyToManyField(Choice)#Crea la tabla de la que hablo
    publicado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name= "encuesta" 
        verbose_name_plural= "encuestas"
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.pregunta
```

Cuando los cree, en la base de datos se creó una tabla nueva llamada: AppPoll_encuesta_opciones
Esta tabla corresponde a las id de la pregunta en Encuesta y la id de las opciones asociadas, el asunto es q no sé como hacer referencia a esta tabla desde Django(Django no lo reconoce), porque la necesito para poder diferenciar entre las opciones de una pregunta y otra, para poder mostrar solo las opciones correspondientes a cada pregunta de la encuesta.
No puedo simplemente escribir: AppPoll_encuesta_opciones.objects.all()
Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder acceder a esa tabla es a través de la opción through, puedes leer mas sobre esto aqui: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through

Para acceder es de la siguiente manera:

```
ejemplo1 = Encuesta.opciones.through # miapp.models.AppPoll_encuesta_opciones
todos = Encuesta.opciones.through.objects.all() # Obtener todos los elementos de la tabla intermedia
nuevo = Encuesta.opciones.through.objects.create(encuesta=None, opciones=None) # Crear un objeto en la tabla intermedia
```